# ng-deep for customizing mat-tab-header causing css conflict

Tags: css, angular

I have two pages and I am trying to navigate between two pages each of them has "mat-tab"

the style of the first one has:

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-header {
  height: 12vh;
}
```

the style of the second one :

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-header {
  height: 8vh;
}
```

after navigating from the second page to the first page again still the height 8vh

and I think the conflict because I am using '::ng-deep' so is there a way to change .mat-tab-header height without using '::ng-deep' ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's customizable in that way that you need, but you can achieve that with `::ng-deep` alongside with `:host` selector. In that way you will **bound** styles to your **component**.
For example:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
  height: 12vh;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
  height: 8vh;
}
```

That should solve your problem. Hope that helps.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it helped